# Importxml function to import data from a website into Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, yahoo-finance

I have not been able to import data from this website into google sheet.

I used the following formula : `=importxml("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/20MICRONS.NS?p=20MICRONS.NS&.tsrc=fin-srch", "//span[@class = 'Fw(600)']")`

[image of the element to be copied and its xml view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIjqB.jpg)

[link image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZB4Hn.png)

upon using the above formula, I get results in google sheets such as "resource not found at URL" and other issues.

Comment: No I haven't done that

Answer (score 0):

`ImportXML` is good for basic tasks, but won't get you too far if you are serious in scraping:

- The approach only works with most basic websites (no SPAs rendered in browsers can be scraped this way, any basic web scraping protection or connectivity issue breaks the process, no control over HTTP request geo location, or number of retries) - and yahoo finance is not a simple website
- If the target website data requires some cleanup post-processing, it's getting very complicated since you are now "programming with excel formulas", rather painful process compared to regular code writing in conventional programming languages
- There is no proper launch & cache control so the function can be triggered occasionally and if the HTTP request fails, cells will be populated with ERR! values

I recommend using proper tools (automation framework + scraping engine) and use Google Sheets just for basic storage purposes:
https://youtu.be/uBC752CWTew (Pipedream for automation + ScrapeNinja engine for scraping)